# What is the ordinal for 2.5?

Tags: ordinal-numbers

In the literature, there are "second degree of XX" and "third degree of XX". I was trying to consider a mix of them, and was considering naming it as "2.5 (ordinal) degree of XX". I was wondering what the ordinal of 2.5 is. Thank you very much!

Comment: "In the literature" - which literature? What context are you trying to use this in?

Comment: They are terms in economics.

Comment: There's only one number in the series so its ordinal is 1.

Comment: There is no ordinal, in the literal sense, corresponding to 2.5, so there is no standard, established way of expressing it in English. Trying to express it would be a playful departure from standard usage; as you are the one choosing to make that departure, it is up to you to decide how to do it.

Comment: .Ordinal numbers are used for setting items in a list, serially arranged according to some criterion.  So can you supply a number of items according to criteria that would render 2.5 an item in that list?  Let's suppose the item is 'halves-above zero'.  Then 2.5 is the fifth.  Unless you can suggest some set of items that require a fractional ordinal, there is no use for such a fractional ordinal.

Comment: There is no ordinal for half, 1.5, etc. Wiktionary has "halfth" as non-standard, e.g. in the context "one and a halfth birthday". Obviously you can write "two and a halfth", but don't expect your spell-checker to like it.